# Setup one to many relation with fk having multiple rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-core-2.2

I have a problem with setting up a one-to-many relation with EF Core.
I have two tables `address` and `address_country`. There are schemas:
[image: address table schema]
[image: address_country table schema]
As you see, I want to store countries with different locales. So it has a composed key. `address` table has a foreign key to `address_country`. Unfortunately, I cannot setup `ContextDb` to achieve what I want. The list of countries is not filled in `Address` model.
I have the following code in `Context`:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(
            @"Data Source=addresses.db");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDto>()
            .ToTable("address");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CountryLocaleDto>()
            .ToTable("address_country");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CountryLocaleDto>()
            .HasKey(cl => new {cl.Id, cl.Locale});

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<AddressDto> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

And my models are

```
public class AddressDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<CountryLocaleDto> CountryLocale { get; set; }
}
public class CountryLocaleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

There is no exception. I simply don't know how to configure this kind of relation. Can anyone help me with that, please?

Example data would be:
**address**

| id | countryId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

**address_country**

| id | locale | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'en' | 'Germany' |
| 1 | 'de' | 'Deutschland' |

An example solution with SQLite db can be found with [this link](https://github.com/VitaliiIsaenko/ef-core-example-relation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right - you just need to add this code to your context class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDto>()
            .HasMany(e=>e.CountryLocale)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x=>x.Id)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x=>x.CountryId);
```

Here you have to add *HasForeignKey* and *HasPrincipalKey*

The Entity Framework Core Fluent API **HasForeignKey** method is used to specify which property is the foreign key in a relationship.

**Principal key**: The property(s) that uniquely identifies the principal entity. This may be the primary key or an alternate key. **Navigation property**: A property defined on the principal and/or dependent entity that contains a reference(s) to the related entity(s).

your model should look like that

```
public class AddressDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<CountryLocaleDto> CountryLocale { get; set; }
}
public class CountryLocaleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

I mean you don't have to add anything else in your model.

I hope it was helpful.

**P.S. Appreciate adding the sample project**

Answer (score 0):

I can see your problem now. If `address` has a foreign key to `address_country`, then that means that One `AddressDto` can have only One `CountryLocaleDto`. If you want one `address` to connect to mane `address_country`, then in your address_country you should have a foreign key to `address`

If you want to have a Many to Many relationship, then you need an intermediary table the `address_country_address`

If you go with the first solution, then you can add the `AddressId` column in your `address_country` and extend your `CountryLocaleDto` like this:

```
public class CountryLocaleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public int AddressId {get; set;}
}
```

Then do the following?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDto>()
    .HasMany(c => c.CountryLocaleDto)
    .WithOne(a => a.AddressDto);
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryId);
    .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Id);
```

That is generally the way we declare the one Address to Many CountryLocale.

## Edit

After the comments, we figured out that there is a CountryId column in the `address` table.

Since we need to change the Principal key from one to the other, then we need to use the [alternate keys solution from microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys)

> Relationships that are discovered by convention will always target the
>   primary key of the principal entity. To target an alternate key,
>   additional configuration must be performed using the Fluent API.

Comment: Yes, then I have the exception `'no such column: a.CountryLocale.AddressId'` as there is no back reference from `address_country` to `address`

Comment: Sorry, one country has many Addresses and not the other way around.

Comment: `CountryLocale` is a list for me but `.WithOne()` method requires one entity to be returned

Comment: Check updated answer. Your current implementation is One Country locale to Many Addresses and not the other way around. It's more a db design problem than a c# problem.

Comment: Thank you! I checked it out. Why would I want to have `addressId` in my `address_country` table? Do you understand that I can work with this db structure and it fits perfect to me but there is just EF problem that I have to solve? I am sure that it is not the best design of tables and relations between them but I'd like to stick to it. I have one address that has one `countryId`. This `countryId` is the same for multiple rows in `address_country` table because of different locales. But there is no relation to address from country as there can be many addresses with the same country.

Comment: Ok, then why don't you migrate the country id to Address and keep just the locale id in your locale table? Think of it this way. In SQL terms, how would you select all the addresses with their corresponding address_country? You can only correlate one Address to exaclty one locale.  Create two address_country rows for one Address and see that you can't do it as address has only one pointer value to address_country.

Comment: I'd write something like `SELECT * FROM address a JOIN address_country ac ON ac.id = a.countryId`. One pointer is enough because both values in `address_country` have the same id.

Comment: Just added example data to the question, maybe you also didn't get that those ids in my `address_country` table are the same for the same country. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try adding the CountryId as the foreign key to the relationship then (check updated answer). Have not tried it live, so please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202578/discussion-between-vitalii-isaenko-and-athanasios-kataras).

Comment: Unfortunately, the last update you offered to try does not work as the `x` that I work within `.HasForeignKey()` method is `CountryLocaleDto` object, not and `AddressDto` object.

Comment: I cannot set the keys the way you propose because in this line `.HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryId);` `a` is an instance of `CountryLocaleDto` and doesn't have `CountryId` field. Yes, `address` has and always had `countryId` field(not only from comments, I added images with table schemas).

Comment: Thank you for the source, I will investigate this option!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class AddressDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public List<CountryLocaleDto> CountryLocale { get; set; }
    }
    public class CountryLocaleDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Locale { get; set; }
        public int AddressDtoId {get; set;}
        public AddressDto Address {get; set;}
    }

   modelBuilder.Entity<CountryLocaleDto>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Address)
                .WithMany(b => b.CountryLocale);
```

This should configure the relationship of one to many, with one address to many countries.

Source for this would be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api

As well you can do something like this and remove the AddressDto property from CountryLocaleDto:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<CountryLocaleDto>(model =>
            {
                model.HasOne<AddressDto>()
                      .WithMany()
                      .HasForeignKey(x => x.AddressDtoId);
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDto>()
                .HasMany(b => b.CountryLocale)
                .WithOne();

public class AddressDto
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int CountryId { get; set; }
            public List<CountryLocaleDto> CountryLocale { get; set; }
        }
        public class CountryLocaleDto
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Locale { get; set; }
        }
```

Soure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships - Single navigation Property

Comment: Unfortunately, the first solution does not fill the collection for me. I don't have `addressId` property in `CountryLocaleDto` as there are many addresses related for each country. At the same time several countries (only because of locales) are related to one address.

Comment: The second solution leads to an exception `'no such column: a.CountryLocale.AddressDtoId1'.`, unfortunately

Comment: You would either need to add the property or use a shadow property then, which will be still reflected in your database. Probably as well this exception is because you have not added a new migration and have not applied it to the database. Use:
`Add-Migration AddedNewProperty` then use `Update-database` inside package manager console which targets your context project.

Comment: So this will add the addressId property to my `address_country` table? But it's not something I want because there can be many addresses with the same country.

Comment: How would you reference it otherway? how one suppose to know about the other?  You can have a model representing your structure, however when you create the migration ef core will automatically add a shadow property and your database will have the value of either reference to one table or the other in the form of id.

Comment: I have a `countryId` in `address` table (and model) and that's how it is supposed to know which country the address has. But as for the model - I don't really know how should they know about each other, preferable way is a list but I don't know how to set up this relation and therefore posted this question.

Comment: Just added example data in the question, check it out, please. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try to add migration and update database.

Comment: It didn't help to fill the `CompaniesLocale` collection, unfortunately.

Comment: When you are reading the data did you use Includ clause?

`_dbContext.Address.Include(x=>x.CountryLocale).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Yes, correct, as in the example solution :)  `context.Addresses.Include(a => a.CountryLocale).ToList()`