# Multi-language support EF Core value tables

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, multilingual, ef-core-3.1

I got a problem with mapping my relation schema with multi-language support with EF Core ORM and desperately looking for help.
I have an `Event` table `(int id, text name, int typeId)` and `EventTypeLocale` table `(int id, text locale, text name)`.

To explain why I cannot restructure my db schema to attach `EventId` to `EventTypeLocale` table - there is an example content in `EventTypeLocale`:

```
(1,'en', 'External event')
(1,'de','Externe Veranstaltung')
(2,'en', 'Internal event ')
(2,'de','Internes Ereignis')
```

And `Event` table has info about session + its type - `typeId` that should reference `EventTypeLocale` with FK. But, as you can see from the example data - there will be several database rows by one id (since there is a composite key `id + locale`). I want to load the type in all locates into the `EventTypeLocales` collection.

I have two classes

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public List<EventTypeLocale> EventTypeLocales { get; set; }
}
public class EventTypeLocale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The complex part is to configure it in the `Context : DbContext` class. Could you help me to configure such a relation?

[I posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914671/setup-one-to-many-relation-with-fk-having-multiple-rows) that basically represents the same problem for a bit more difficult case. Unfortunately, the proposed solution works only for fetching data but when I try to update `Event` object with another `TypeId` - EF doesn't allow it (since in the proposed solution `TypeId` is configured as a PrincipleKey. Therefore, the accepted solution in the previous post doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I am not sure why it should be that complex, keep foreign key in one model, and use navigation collection in another

Comment: I also think such a case should be supported by EF Core. Or do you suggest me to restructure my DB schema? I'll add example data in the `SessionTypeLocale` table so it's clear that it shouldn't reference `Session` table

Comment: you don't need to change schema, remove `Session.SessionTypeLocales`and add `SessionTypeLocale.Sessions`, if you have one-to-many relationship. one session can navigate to only one locale, and locale can be used by many sessions

Comment: so if you need to get all sessions with Session.TypeId, you will navigate  with `Session.SessionTypeLocale.Sessions`

Comment: True, that might work, but when I get a session I need it's type with all locales. So you just change the rule and that's not what I need to work with `Session` object

Comment: No, I never need all sessions with the same typeId, what I need is to get type in all locales when I get sessions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223965/discussion-between-yegor-androsov-and-vitalii-isaenko).